# como convertir un json en un objeto en python?

Tags: python, json, poo, diccionarios, str

Cordial saludo...

estoy trabajando en un proyecto personal "ChatBOT" https://github.com/felipedelosh/ChatBotByLokov1.0

Pero tengo un inconveniente:

Las preguntas se cargan desde archivos json:

https://github.com/felipedelosh/ChatBotByLokov1.0/tree/main/Resources/Questions

Que hacen referencia al objeto pregunta:
https://github.com/felipedelosh/ChatBotByLokov1.0/blob/main/Question.py

Mi pregunta es como hago para convertir automáticamente los archivos json en un objeto de tipo pregunta?

Mi código es el siguiente:
https://github.com/felipedelosh/ChatBotByLokov1.0/blob/main/Controller.py
linea 64.

```
    brute_data = self.rtnArcheveInfo(path_file+i)
    json_data = json.loads(brute_data)

    _bot_response = json_data['bot_response']
    _list_of_words = json_data['list_of_words']
    _single_response = json_data['single_response']
    _required_words = json_data['required_words']

    q = Question(_bot_response, _list_of_words, _single_response, _required_words)

    self.questions.append(q)
```

Y lo estoy haciendo de manera manual por qué no conozco como hacerlo como hacerlo automadicamente como en .net

Busco algo como question = Json.Decode(json_data, Question)

Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: Si que el diccionario guardado en json_data tiene de clave el nombre del parametro y como valor el argumento y no sobran ni faltan argumentos, entonces, podrías desempaquetar el diccionario en forma de argumentos nombrados usando `Question(**json_data)`, lo cual sería equivalente a `Question(bot_response=json_data['bot_response'], ...)`, pero usando los pares clave-valor del diccionario como si fueran argumentos.

Comment: Efectivamente... Con solo expandir el diccionario se crearón los objetos correctamente... Muchas gracias caballero.

Comment: De nada compañero!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
        json_data = json.loads(brute_data)
        q = Question(**json_data)
        self.questions.append(q)
```

Comment: ¿Es una respuesta o información adicional para la pregunta? Si es el segundo caso, esto debería ser una edición.

Comment: @Mateo casi seguro que es una respuesta relacionada a mis comentarios. Pues en el código está aplicando la solución que le propuse.

Comment: Las respuestas que proporcionan solo código sin explicaciones se consideran de baja calidad. Para mejorarla podrías explicar qué hace el operador `**` y por qué eso es la solución apropiada para este caso.